# Select value from left table and full join right table

Tags: mysql, join

This is a bit difficult to explain, but I'll give my best:

Let's say, I have table A:

```
event | task | ref_person
------+------+-----------
  1   |  20  |     1
  2   |   9  |     2
```

And I have table B (containing `person`):

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
 3 | jim
```

What does a MySQL-query look like, that produces this sort of table:

```
 event | task | person
 ------+------+-------
   1   |  20  |   foo
   1   | NULL |   bar
   1   | NULL |   jim
   2   | NULL |   foo
   2   |   9  |   bar
   2   | NULL |   jim
```

My current approach is by using a `RIGHT JOIN`, but this won't get me  the event combined with the NULL-value.

This is what my current statement looks like:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.name

FROM
    a

RIGHT JOIN b
    ON b.id = a.ref_person

ORDER BY 
    a.event,
    b.name
```

## Notice

sqlfiddle seems down, I'll add one as soon as it's up again

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a `cross join` to get all the rows, then `case` logic to get the task:

```
select a.event,
       (case when a.ref_person = b.id then a.task end) as task,
       b.name
from tablea a cross join
     tableb b ;
```